# Should a question that was not directly a programming problem or error but a code copying problem be deleted?

Tags: discussion

For example, I posted this question: [Istanbul keeps saying that “if Path” is not taken but test for that exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52801861/istanbul-keeps-saying-that-if-path-is-not-taken-but-test-for-that-exist/52801978#52801978). The problem wasn't about jasmine config or angular config, etc. but an error where I was calling a wrong function (because of a copy/paste error).

There is a answer there that pointed out that error.

Should I delete this question?

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot delete your question as the answer has an upvote.

Comment: It is my upvote. I thought about this after I mark it as solved.

Comment: If you unupvote and unaccept, you can delete it.

Comment: Generally: yes, questions which are based on typos should be deleted, as they’re unlikely to help anyone else in the future. They’re clutter. If you have the option to delete, do so. Otherwise, nbd.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, we have a close reason for user error scenarios such as this (under the umbrella term "typo"), and such questions are expected to go away eventually. There is nothing wrong with expediting this process yourself by deleting your own question if you are able.

If you can't delete your question because other people have upvoted answers to it, don't worry about it. Other users with the right privileges, if they're so inclined, will delete your question for you.

Comment: I see it now with downvotes and already marked as "off topic". Sadly I can not delete it but somebody already closed it.